# Entity Framework is not working on desktop

Tags: c#

I used entity framework with Visual Studio 2012. Everything is working correctly , but when SaveChanges() call occurs, It shows Addition successful message but data is not inserting in database. Can someone help me?

Here is the code and link of complete project.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzGC-O73lSx7UDd4NFVxRXQyVG8/edit?usp=sharing

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
     Student s = new Student();
     s.Name = StudentName.Text;              
     s.Address = Address.Text;

     db.Students.Add(s);
     if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Addition Successfull");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Addition Failed");
     }
}
```

And my database script.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Id]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Address] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: ButtGenius Can you show us `connection string`? It is in App.Config File within <connectionstring> Tag.

Comment: I think you should not add condition. just write `db.SaveChanges();` and check out changes in database.

Comment: Here it is
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Well i think ConnectionString is ok -- `(LocalDB)\v11.0` is your ServerName right? Secondly have you set `PrimaryKey` to generate automatically?

Comment: Yes i am using auto generation Primary key
thats why i am not adding it manually in the code

Comment: How to verify my server name is (LocalDB)\v11.0

Comment: When you connect to `Sql Server Management Studio` While connectivity it will show you your server name -- Are you using Entity FrameWork?

Comment: Yes I am using **Entity Framework**

Comment: I think you can easily understand my problem if you download the source code from the link and run it.....

Comment: Well this is really strange code provided by `meda` is perfectly fine -- ok let me build your this application here on my PC

Comment: thats great!
waiting for your reply..

Comment: buttgenius2000@gmial.com

Comment: Yes its gmail...Sorry for late reply

Comment: I didn't receive the mail.

Comment: buttgenius2000@gmail.com

Comment: ok Gmail doesn't allow to email this -- i am uploading on skydrive wait/

Comment: Still no mail...try this abdulwahab.pucit@gmail.com

Comment: ok i have uploaded here https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=BA764F32F7BE590D&id=BA764F32F7BE590D%21107 ... Read Note in Notepad carefully and secondly watch video in this folder, it may help you to get more clear with solution--open video via Internet Explorer  -- my uploaded application is working very fine on my PC  and let me know if you need more assistance in this regard.

Comment: The link shows the message "This item might not exist or is no longer available"

Comment: try this https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=BA764F32F7BE590D&id=BA764F32F7BE590D%21107#cid=BA764F32F7BE590D

Comment: Now the latest link shows the message "Tameen malik isn't sharing anything"

Comment: o ho i apologize for this let me share this

Comment: try this https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=BA764F32F7BE590D!107

Comment: Got the file Butt.rar

Comment: Thank's Allah ! ok let me know the results

Comment: Thanks for giving so much time to solve my problem...

Comment: No problem at all ! stackoverflow is here to solve problems :)

Comment: have your problem solved?

Comment: Thanks alot **Tameen Malik** that problem was solved on demo project...But I am using N-Tier architecture and I thought that the solution will work on it as well but its not working on N-Tier Architecture...I am little bit messed up :(

Answer (score 0):

You are validating using this condition:

```
if (db.SaveChanges() >= 0)
```

So if 0 you still print `Addition Successfull`

You should catch an exception instead, if you don't get one then it's successful:

```
 using (var db = new Database1Entities())
 {
 Student s = new Student();
 s.Name = StudentName.Text;              
 s.Address = Address.Text;

 try 
 {
     db.Students.Add(s);
     int numOfUpdate = db.SaveChanges();
     MessageBox.Show("Addition Successfull:" + numOfUpdate.ToString() + "updates");
 }
 catch(Execption ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Addition Failed:" + ex.Message);
 }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code...
and it shows a message "Addition Successfull:1 updates".
but still not showing in database :(

Comment: SaveChanges returns the number of rows affected, so I'd say zero also means failure.